# storing data in realm database with relationships swift

Tags: ios, swift, database, list, realm

So I am trying to use realm database for my application for the first time. I am trying to create a relationship in database.

here is the json

```
{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Definizioni generali - Doveri nell'uso della strada",
            "image": "559",
            "video": "0",
            "created_at": "2019-03-14 22:27:23",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-14 22:27:23",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "id": 3110,
                    "chapter_id": 1,
                    "name": "a) Definizioni stradali e di traffico",
                    "created_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52",
                    "updated_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3123,
                    "chapter_id": 1,
                    "name": "b) Definizioni e classificazione dei veicoli",
                    "created_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52",
                    "updated_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3131,
                    "chapter_id": 1,
                    "name": "c) Doveri del conducente nell'uso della strada - Convivenza civile e uso responsabile della strada",
                    "created_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52",
                    "updated_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52"
                },
                {
                    "id": 3137,
                    "chapter_id": 1,
                    "name": "d) Riguardo verso gli utenti deboli della strada",
                    "created_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52",
                    "updated_at": "2019-03-14 22:30:52"
                }
            ]
        }
```

this is my chapter class

```
class Chapter: Object, Mappable {
@objc dynamic var id:Int = -1
@objc dynamic var name: String = kBlankString
@objc dynamic var image: String = kBlankString
@objc dynamic var video: String = kBlankString
@objc dynamic var createdAt: String = kBlankString
@objc dynamic var updatedAt: String = kBlankString
var sections = List<Section>()

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}

required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    image <- map["image"]
    video <- map["video"]
    createdAt <- map["created_at"]
    updatedAt <- map["updated_at"]
    sections <- map["sections"]


}
```

}

Here on this line `sections <- map["sections"]`

I added a breakpoint and checked `po map["sections"].JSON`

it is showing the data here.

the problem is that chapters are being stored in database but section list is empty for every chapter which is not true

here is the section class:

```
class Section: Object, Mappable {
@objc dynamic var id: Int = -1
@objc dynamic var chapterID: Int = -1
@objc dynamic var name: String = kBlankString
@objc dynamic var createdAt: String = kBlankString
@objc dynamic var updatedAt: String = kBlankString

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}


required convenience init?(map: Map) {
    self.init()
}

func mapping(map: Map) {
    id <- map["id"]
    chapterID <- map["chapter_id"]
    name <- map["name"]
    createdAt <- map["created_at"]
    updatedAt <- map["updated_at"]

}
```

}

Please guide me if i am doing something incorrect, this is my first attempt with realm database. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I assume this is using ObjectMapper (https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper), which I haven't myself used.

But the problem will be that the map you're trying to do for the sections will give you an array type (as I understand it), but Realm does not support arrays (as you know, as you've correctly used `List`).

I think you'll need a custom transform (https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/ObjectMapper#custom-transforms) to convert to a `List<>` type instead. The [RealmAdditions](https://github.com/APUtils/ObjectMapperAdditions#realm-features) shows how to do this. That shows an equivalent line to do what you want in the sample code - the important bit is this line (translated to use your types):

```
        sections <- (map["sections"], ListTransform<Section>())
```

Comment: The pod pod 'ObjectMapper+Realm' did the trick for me thanks for the hint. You are a life saviour.